# Saving values from a function call in a for loop

Tags: python

I want to save the values from the function call in a txt file but I am getting the typeerror: expected a character buffer object

```
def printme( x ):
    "Function f(x) = x(x+2)"
    print x*(x+2)
    return

myfile = open('xyz.txt', 'w')
    for w in b:
        myfile.write('%d' (printme(w)))

myfile.close()
```

Comment: Please post the actual error, with traceback, not a description of it.

Comment: You can only write strings to files. Other than that your `printme` function doesnt return 'anything' so youre trying to write 'nothing' to your file at the moment

Comment: indentation is broken at first place use `myfile.write("{}".format(printme(w)))`

Comment: The code you showed us does not demonstrate the problem you describe. It actually raises a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`. That's because `anything (anything_else)` is a call to `anything` as a function, so `'%d' (printme(w))` is a call to `'%d'` as a function, which makes no sense.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Your suggested code won't work. First, presumably you meant `format` rather than `formate`. Second, you can't use `format` without adding `{}` placeholders.

Comment: @abarnert yes my mistake,Thanks, I corrected my comment, please verify again

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: OK, now that line is valid. But really, there's no reason he has to use `format` instead of `%` here. That doesn't solve the problem so much as replace it without explanation. And it still won't work without fixing all of the other problems.

Comment: @abarnert ultimate answer from top to bottom. thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are at least four problems with your code as posted, and none of them will demonstrate the error you're actually seeing.

---

First, there's an `IndentationError`:

```
myfile = open('xyz.txt', 'w')
    for w in b:
    myfile.write('%d' (printme(w)))
```

You can't randomly indent code wherever you want; the `for` statement follows the assignment statement, and the `myfile.write` call is supposed to be inside the `for` loop. So:

```
myfile = open('xyz.txt', 'w')
for w in b:
    myfile.write('%d' (printme(w)))
```

---

If you fix that, your next error will be a `TypeError`, but it will be for `'str' object is not callable`, not anything about a character buffer object.

In Python, anything of the form `foo (bar)` is a function call—an attempt to call `foo` like a function, with `bar` as its only argument. So, this expression:

```
'%d' (printme(w))
```

… attempts to call the string `'%d'` as a function, passing the result of `printme(w)` as its only argument. That's obviously not going to work, because strings aren't callable like functions. Hence the exception.

---

You probably wanted to use the `%` operator there, like this:

```
'%d' % (printme(w))
```

That's close, but still not quite right, because `(printme(w))` is not a tuple of one value. Tuples are created by commas, not by parentheses, so a tuple of one value has to have a comma in it. So:

```
'%d' % (printme(w),)
```

(You don't actually *need* a tuple here, because `%` has special handling for single values. But if you're *trying* to create a tuple, you should get it right, not get it wrong and have your code possibly work anyway…)

---

And now we're getting close, but we've got another problem: `printme` doesn't return a number, it *prints* a number, and then returns `None`. (That's the default value you get from any function that doesn't `return` something different.) So, the `%` operator will give you yet another `TypeError`, this time saying `'%d" format: a number is required, not NoneType`.

To fix that, you want to `return` the value instead of (or in addition to) printing it:

```
def printme( x ):
    "Function f(x) = x(x+2)"
    return x*(x+2)
```

Of course a function named `printme` that instead returns a value is a bit misleading, so you might want to rename it at this point…

---

If you fix that, then everything works. There is no `TypeError` saying `expected a character buffer object` anywhere.

Most likely, in your *actual* code, you're trying to `write` the value you got back from `printme`, *without* formatting it into a string first (with that `%` operator or otherwise). For example, if you do this:

```
myfile.write(printme(w))
```

… that's either trying to write `None` (if you didn't fix the last problem) or some number (if you did), neither of which is a string (or other "character buffer object"), hence the error.

To fix that, just use the code you showed us instead of different code.

---

Putting it all together, here's working code that does what you're apparently trying to do:

```
def printme( x ):
    "Function f(x) = x(x+2)"
    return x*(x+2)

myfile = open('xyz.txt', 'w')
for w in b:
    myfile.write('%d' % (printme(w),))

myfile.close()
```

Comment: Works perf. - thx. If I want to add a breakline between every number in the list b I am iterating should this be added in the for loop?

Comment: @user2128383: Yes. Since you're already using `%`-formatting, the obvious way to do that is to add it to the format string: `myfile.write('%d\n' % (printme(w),))`. If you prefer to make it a separate write instead, of course you can do that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

```
def printme( x ):
    "Function f(x) = x(x+2)"
    return x*(x+2)

b = [1,2,3,4,5]

myfile = open('xyz.txt', 'w')

for w in b:
    myfile.write(str(printme(w)))
    myfile.write("\n")

# !!! EDIT !!!
myfile.close()
```

Comment: You've changed the output format from what his code was attempting (what makes you think he wants a newline after the numbers if he doesn't want spaces between them?), and actually made his code worse by forgetting to `close` the file, and didn't explain any of the multiple changes you made to his code…

Comment: doh! I missed the last line in the copy :P sorry. about the \n I guessed he would wanted it.

Comment: That should do the trick - thx. But my txt file does not show any breaklines!

Comment: I guessed right. you can do it in one line if you want. I've separated   because it was my adding.

Comment: ahah sorry!! I'm on linux I don't need \r :D